# firebase connection lost after add another app

Tags: android, firebase

I am building two apps with one firebase database like admin app and user app. I build admin app. I can upload and retrieve data successfully. After that I created a module for user app and did connect with firebase. After that I lost access to firebase from admin app. I can't upload to firebase or retrieve data from firebase. Still new app (user app) can retrieve. only the access of old app lost which was working perfectly before. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What do you mean by "I lost access to Firebase from admin app"? Do you have any errors?

Comment: No error. But when uploading data, nothing uploading. When retrieve data nothing shows in recyclerview. actually this is happening every time when 
I am signing in. It will work perfectly after clear data of app from android device. And issue will there again when signed in.

Comment: In that case, show us the code that behaves that way.